# How to transfer data of selected row in gridview to another aspx page into asp controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i don't understand where to write code for this operation.

I tried to implement code from following link https://forums.asp.net/t/2130391.aspx?RowEditing+in+GridView+in+c+ of Cathy Zou. But didn't understand code behind.

This is my gridview code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  >
     <Columns>                            
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="pass" HeaderText="pass" SortExpression="pass" />
         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="false" ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="Edit" EditImageUrl="~/images/editicon.jpg"/>
         <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="false"  ButtonType="Image" HeaderText="delete" DeleteImageUrl="~/images/deleteicon.png"/>
     </Columns>
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewheader" />
     <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewrow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my codebehind code.

```
public string cnstring = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!this.IsPostBack)
   {
       binddata();
   }
}

protected void binddata()
{

}
```

I have two pages, called addproduct.aspx and editproduct.aspx. In addproduct.aspx page i have gridview along with Edit and delete commandfield. When i click on edit it should redirect me to editproduct.aspx page with selected row data.

My requirement is, i want to display edit icon for edit instead edit link. 
When i click on edit icon it should work according to my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a TemplateField instead of CommandField, so you can add an asp:Button like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pass" HeaderText="pass" SortExpression="pass" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server"  ID="deleteButton" OnClick="deleteButton_Click" Text="Delete"/>                    
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="editButton" OnClick="editButton_Click" Text="Edit"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>            
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridviewheader" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="gridviewrow" />
</asp:GridView>
```

And in the `addproduct.aspx`, inside the OnClick event, capture the row data and send it to `editproduct.aspx` like this:

```
string id = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
//sending the datafield "id" to the other webform
Response.Redirect("editproduct.aspx?idParameter=id");
```